# How to switch to "work profile" on phone running Android 10

Tags: profiles, work-profiles

How to switch to Work Profile on Samsung Galaxy Note 9 running Android 10?
All the guides I find online are related to tablets and/or they point to menus that are not available on the official Android 10 running on my phone.

Comment: Did you add an account with a work-related email address from the company? (For more information about Work Profile: [What is a work profile?](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949)

Comment: No, I have not. Can I use the work profile not linking it to any account?
If this is not possible, can I just activate the work profile with another random email address I create?